# Is there anyway to print clients ip address using python?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

```
db.currentOp(true).inprog.forEach(function(d){if(d.client)print(d.client, d.connectionId)})
```

output:

```
127.0.0.1:64629 383
127.0.0.1:56878 363
```

I used this command to get IP address of client in shell.
is there is any way to get it in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [manual page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/) for `db.currentOp` says

> db.currentOp wraps the database command currentOp.

So once we know that, we can use the `db.command()` in pymongo, and replicate your javascript as follows:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()['admin']
command_result = db.command({'currentOp': 1})
inprogs = command_result.get('inprog')

for inprog in inprogs:
    if 'client' in inprog:
        print(inprog.get('client'), inprog.get('connectionId'))
```

gives (e.g.):

```
172.17.0.1:39734 15
```